# Incluir librería de internet en un archivo con extensión (.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-import

Sucede que estoy en mi archivo **ejemplo.js** y necesito incluir una librería de internet *(Ej: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)*, el dilema es que no lo puedo hacer de la forma convencional usando las etiquetas `<script></script>`, puesto que se trata de un archivo con extensión **.js** que sería:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`. **=>(Esto me genera error)**

He intentado esto:

`import "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //...Resto de código...
});
```

Pero me aparece esto:

`SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

Comment: que error te genera `<script ...` ?

Comment: Me genera `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`, pero esto se debe a que **<script ...** no es una etiqueta válida para el archivo `.js`

Comment: claro, ahora entendí la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres hacer `import` de jquery u otro .js desde un archivo `ejemplo.js` que se ejecutará en un navegador y en un servidor, tienes que hacer esto:

En el HTML:

```
<script type="module" src="ejemplo.js"></script>
```

En `ejemplo.js`:

```
import 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
```

Lo que permite hacer `import` es el atributo `type="module"` de la etiqueta `<script>`.

En cuanto a la compatibilidad, ver [`import` en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/M%C3%B3dulos#Soporte_del_navegador). Internet Explorer no lo soporta.